# Run a function inside a while loop inside a string?

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to generate an email to include some sorted data in the body.
My email sends but does not have the data in the body from the functions. by functions are also while loops and they generate echoed html content if that makes sense?
here is one of the functions.

```
function ye($coid){
$yest = date("Y-m-d", time() - 86400);
$inouty= mysql_query("SELECT clockings.id AS cid,clockings.uid, clockings.con,        clockings.coff, staff.sname ,staff.id, staff.act, staff.coid FROM clockings LEFT JOIN staff ON clockings.uid=staff.id WHERE clockings.dte = '$yest' AND staff.coid =$coid ORDER BY staff.id, clockings.id")or die(mysql_error());
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($inouty)) {
       $sname= $row['sname'];
       $in=  $row['con'];
       $out= "- ". $row['coff'];
       $id = $row['cid'];               
echo"$sname $in $out<br>";}}
```

and this is where i call it

```
$html_text = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd'>
                  <html>
                     <head>
                        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
                        <title>Email</title>
                     </head>

                     <body>details Current status for $nicedate as of $now<br>". tod($coid)."<br>Yesterdays Clockings<br>". ye($coid)."</body>
                  </html>";
```

No if I change the function to return a value instead of echoing i get just the first row of results instead of the full loop but that is included in the email body text and also when i call the function at the end of the script using echo in my function i get the desired output. 
Is there any way i can get this to work? Thanks in advance Nick

Comment: have you tried a "sandbox" to echo $inouty ? also seperate $inouty and work with it from there ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your call is trying to include the result of the function, you'll just need to make sure you're returning *all* the lines generated along the way. There are many ways to do that, here's one:

```
function ye($coid)
{
  $yest = date("Y-m-d", time() - 86400);
  $inouty= mysql_query("SELECT clockings.id AS cid,clockings.uid, clockings.con,        clockings.coff, staff.sname ,staff.id, staff.act, staff.coid FROM clockings LEFT JOIN staff ON clockings.uid=staff.id WHERE clockings.dte = '$yest' AND staff.coid =$coid ORDER BY staff.id, clockings.id")or die(mysql_error());

  $result = "";

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($inouty)) {
     $sname = htmlspecialchars($row['sname']);
     $in    = htmlspecialchars($row['con']);
     $out   = "- ". htmlspecialchars($row['coff']);

     $result .= "$sname $in $out<br>";
  }

  return $result;
}
```